# Validate a single property with the Fluent Validation Library for .Net

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, fluentvalidation

Can you validate just a single property with the [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) Library, and if so how? I thought [this discussion thread from January of 2009](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=43798) showed me how to do it via the following syntax:

```
validator.Validate(new Person(), x => x.Surname);
```

Unfortunately it doesn't appear this works in the current version of the library. One other thing that led me to believe that validating a single property might be possible is the following quote from [Jeremy Skinners' blog post](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/02/06/fluentvalidation-1-2-beta-2-and-mvc2-rc2/):

> "Finally, I added the ability to be able to execute some of FluentValidation’s Property Validators without needing to validate the entire object. This means it is now possible to stop the default “A value was required” message from being added to ModelState. "

However I do not know if that necessarily means it supports just validating a single property or the fact that you can tell the validation library to stop validating after the first validation error.

Comment: Literally every link in this post is not working anymore :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this discussion](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=205056) on CodePlex, that ability is added by way of extension methods. You would need to import the FluentValidation namespace to have those show up in IntelliSense.

Comment: FluentValidation.DefaultValidatorExtensions has extension methods for validation by one or more property names. IE

`MyClassValidator.Validate(MyClassInstance, "MyPropertyName")`

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else stumbling upon this problem.
In FluentValidation v9.3.0 you would do:

```
_Validator.Validate(ClassInstance, 
                opt=> opt.IncludeProperties(x => x.SomePropertyOfTheClassInstance));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sebastian.roibu answer, I would like to share my solution as his answer was incomplete for me and hope this will save you time figuring it out.

I had to create a seperate `CustomValidator: AbstractValidator` class first.
This class has the `Validate()` method.

Next, the Validate() method will "do nothing" on it's own, you need to look at the return (`ValidationResult`) which will have all the errors from `CustomValidator`

From ValidationResult I was able to get all the errors for that 1 property, and attach it to my current context that wasn't validating this that way.

Here is my full answer on validating "PATCH" operation using JsonPatchDocument:

```
    public PatchCommandValidator()
    {
        RuleForEach(x => x.JsonPatchDocument.Operations)
            .CustomAsync(HandleOperationValidation);
    }

    private async Task HandleOperationValidation(Operation<BasketHeaderPatchModel> property, ValidationContext<PatchBasketHeaderCommand> context, CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        var requestModel = new RequestModel();

        var propertyInfo = requestModel.GetType().GetProperty(property.path.Replace("/", ""));
        propertyInfo.SetValue(basketHeaderPatchModel, Convert.ChangeType(property.value, propertyInfo.PropertyType));

        var customValidator = new CustomValidator();

        var result = await customValidator.ValidateAsync(requestModel , x => x.IncludeProperties(propertyInfo.Name), cancellation);

        result.Errors.ForEach(context.AddFailure);

    }
```